# Отправка данных с формы на почту PHP

Tags: php, html5

Реализовал обработчик формы, но данные по какой-то причине не отправляются.

```
<?php
// почта получателя
$to  = 'silischtschew.d@gmail.com';

// тема письма
$subject = 'Письмо с данными формы моего сайта';

// текст письма
$message = 'Пользователь желает поехать в страну ' . $_POST['country'] . ', в город ' . 
$_POST['city'] . '<br />
Предполагаемая дата отправления: ' . $_POST['date'] . '; Продолжительность: ' . $_POST['duration'] . 
'<br />
Количество взрослых: ' . $_POST['adult'] . '; детей: ' . $_POST['children']
;

// Для отправки HTML-письма должен быть установлен заголовок Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Дополнительные заголовки
$headers .= 'To: Данил <silischtschew.d@gmail.com>' . "\r\n"; // Свое имя и email


// Отправляем
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас вообще функция `mail` не доставляет популярным почтовым сервисам письма. Как решение проблемы можно и нужно использовать SMPT. Одно из лучших решение - [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Всё зависит от настройки сервера. Функция `mail()` вызывает системную утилиту `sendmail` (или её заглушку - настраивается в `php.ini`). В свою очередь, `sendmail` вполне может быть настроена на работу с SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Тоже советую использовать smtp. Но для отладки mail ()  используйте var_dump ( mail () ). Если вернет false возможно проблема с вашим хостингом. Например, на хостинге может быть ограничено кол-во отправок в единицу времени. Посмотрите ваш тариф или напишите в поддержку

Comment: Для отладки лучше использовать средства отладки IDE, а не вывод на экран. Тоже вариант с выводом, но это уже прошлый век)

Comment: Вы думаете автор вопроса умеет этим пользоваться? ))